# Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto

Tags: excel-vba

Olá. Estou tentando formatar uma tabela para basear um grafo, no entanto estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro: "erro de tempo de execução ‘1004’: erro definido pelo aplicativo ou definido pelo objeto"

Estou usando a seguinte macro. Algo sabe o motivo do erro?
O erro ocorre na linha que >>>marquei<<<

```
Sub Botão_ReplicadorColuna()

Dim i, j, UltimaLinha, UltimaColuna As Long

UltimaLinha = 1000000
UltimaColuna = 30

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For j = 4 To UltimaColuna
    For i = UltimaLinha To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
           Cells(i + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert
           Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
           >>>>Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value<<<<
           Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
           Cells(i, j).Value = ClearContents
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Eu possua duas planilhas. Uma em que a macro está e outra em que eu fiz um tratamento dos dados e depois copiei dela e colei na planilha da macro.

Não há celulas mescladas.

Pude notar que até 100000 linhas a macro funciona perfeitamente. Após isso apresenta o erro.

O que desejo fazer é o seguinte. Quero replicar o id e o conteúdo para cada coluna de tema existente, de forma que uma linha seja formada por apenas três colunas.

```
    **Original:**
    ID / Content / Theme
    1 / words / theme/ theme2/ theme3
    2 / words / theme/ them2
    3 / words / theme

    **Pós-macro:**
    ID / Content / Theme
    1 / words / theme
    1 / words / theme2
    1 / words / theme3
    2 / words / theme
    2 / words / theme2
    3 / words / theme
```

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro? Quantas planilhas você possui? Há células mescladas?

Comment: Caso tenha perdido acesso a sua conta original ou deseje mesclá-la com sua nova conta acesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact e escolha o motivo correspondente

Answer (score 0):

Testei e o código funcionou para mim com poucas linhas. Então listarei a seguir mudanças no código e algumas observações do que pode estar acontecendo.

## Loop

Se os dados estiverem desta forma:

```
  1   words   theme   theme2   theme3  
  2   words   theme                    
  3   words   theme   them2
```

O código já não funciona...

Então sugiro inverter o loop para:

```
For i = 1 To UltimaLinha
    For j = UltimaColuna To 4 Step -1
    Next j
Next i
```

## Declaração

A declaração está incorreta desta maneira:

`Dim i, j, UltimaLinha, UltimaColuna As Long`

Em que `i, j, UltimaLinha` estão declarados somente como `Variant` e `UltimaColuna` como `Long`. O correto seria:

`Dim i As Long, j As Long, UltimaLinha As Long, UltimaColuna As Long`

(Sintaxe estranha que ocorre no VBA) O que não tem problema, pois depois elas são transformadas para Long, mas é melhor não deixar o VBA "descobrir" que tipo de variável será usada.

## Limite de Linhas

Não sei a quantidade de dados da planilha, porém o Excel possui um limite de 1 048 576 linhas, portanto quando chega na linha 100 000 ele pode estar tentando inserir uma linha e não há mais espaço. Verifique se esta quantidade de linhas está sendo ultrapassada.

## Declaração da Planilha

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nome_da_planilha")
```

É bom declarar a planilha usada para evitar que ao clicar em outra planilha, a macro seja ativada no local errado.

Ou se estiver em outra Pasta de Trabalho:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\aminho\Para\o\Arquivo\excel.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Nome_da_planilha")
```

## Código

```
Option Explicit
Sub Botão_ReplicadorColuna()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, UltimaLinha As Long, UltimaColuna As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Nome_da_planilha")

    UltimaLinha = 1048576
    UltimaColuna = 30

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        For i = 1 To UltimaLinha
            For j = UltimaColuna To 4 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                    .Cells(i + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                    .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                    .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = .Cells(i, j).Value
                    .Cells(i, j).ClearContents
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Daniel.
Caso eu esteja respondendo utilizando a funcionalidade errada, por favor, me fale que modificarei para a correta.


Tentei por aqui e aplicando o código recebi "erro em tempo de execução 9 - Subscrito fora do intervalo". 

Esse erro está marcando a seguinte linha:

        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Redes_Lula_tratado_pré_macro")

Se eu tento especificar a pasta, o código roda, mas só uma nova planilha é aberta. A macro não inicia.

A pasta em que o arquivo está é "C:\Users\Stilingue\Desktop\redes" e o arquivo é Redes_Lula_tratado_pré_macro.xlsx.

Comment: `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Nome_da_planilha")` é o nome da aba da Planilha e para abrir o arquivo: `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Stilingue\Desktop\redes\Redes_Lula_tratado_pré_macro.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: Obrigado! A aba é chamada ExportSheet. Especifiquei na macro e foi, mas obtive outro erro. Agora voltou a ser erro 1004, "método insert da classe range falhou". Sinalizou a seguinte linha: ".Cells(i + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert"

Comment: Veja a parte da resposta em que falo das linhas, você pode ter alcançado a última linha possível no Excel... ou possui células mescladas.

Comment: Daniel, rodei o programa e apareceu o mesmo erro. A tabela foi tratada até a linha 108629. Depois disso ela seguiu desconfigurada. Verifiquei o número de linhas e não há possibilidade dela passar de 1kk de linhas e nem há células mesclads. No total são 249 mil linhas até o momento e com a formatação iria até 500 mil no máximo. Tem ideia do que pode ser? Tenho uma curiosidade também, utilizei essa macro pra duas linhas e ela demorou cerca de 2 horas para formatá-las. Esse tempo é normal?
Muito obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar!

Comment: Seu código está pesado mesmo, você realiza o loop da primeira linha até a última (mais de 1 milhão) e em 26 colunas (totalizando mais de 26 milhões). Com muitas interações entre o VBE e a planilha Excel, por exemplo inserindo linhas... Para otimizar sugiro trabalhar com matrizes e popular uma nova planilha com dados desta matriz. Ou realizar somente loops até as linhas necessárias, não em todas incluindo inúmeras linhas em branco...